# How to get form variables data into twig templates?

Tags: theming, 8, forms

I have a form like:

```
 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $short_title = '') {
$title = 'xyz';
}
```

In my .module file, I have a theme function:

```
function ip_mcq_theme() {
  return [
    'take_mcq_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
    ],
  ];
}
```

How to get form variables like `$short_title` and `$title` mentioned in form build function in my `take-mcq-form.twig.html` file?

Answer (score 4):

Put the custom variable in a key with a '#', so that the formbuilder doesn't try to render this as a form element.

*buildForm():*

```
  $form['#myvars']['var1'] = 'xyz';
```

In twig you can access the variable in `element`:

*form.html.twig:*

```
  {{ element['#myvars'].var1 }}
```

If you set a template in `#theme` of the form build

*buildForm():*

```
  $form['#theme'] = 'take_mcq_form';
```

you get a second template inside of *form.html.twig*, where you can access the variable in `form`:

*take_mcq_form.html.twig:*

```
  {{ form['#myvars'].var1 }}
```